# How to avoid getting error 'localStorage is not defined' on server in ReactJS Universal App

Tags: reactjs

I was using localStorage in my webApp to store data on client side. But when I've tried to make the app Universal, this causes an issue.  How do I solve this issue?

Comment: You'll need to separate your logic that access `localStorage` to be executed only on client related javascript as localStorage is not available in serverside

Comment: Any method to get Autherized data by using headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem('token') }  in server Side Rendering?

Comment: I hope you need to fetch the auth related data on page load. You can do this by two ways. One if you maintain a server side session. Two you store some data in a cookie that will you can obtain from the request and process based on that. `localStorage`, `sessionStorage` are not accessible from the server.

Comment: ok .....I will Check With cookie ....thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're isomorphically rendering React on the server than the code accessing local storage must be put in componentDidMount as this will not be called on the serverside.